# Howto passing variable from function to another function in controller without use session and call method

Tags: php, laravel

I want to Send $blogId to image funtion image and i can't call image($blog) because receive method get from dropzone. help me please

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
 public $blogId;
 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->blogId;
    $this->middleware('auth');
 }
 public function Create(Request $request)
 {
       $blog = create([
        'title' => $request['title'],
        'content' => $request['content'],
       ]);
       $this->blogId= $blog //Not Wrok
       //session(['blogId' => $blog->id]); No use session
       //image($blog); No use call function
 }
 public function image(Request $request){
    dd($this->blogId);
    // $blogId = session('blogId'); No use session
 } 
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how are you calling `image` function?

Comment: I think you should init $blogId = array(); in the class

Comment: And you can use the $blogId to the function image by add it as dynamic like image( Request $request, $blogId = array())

Comment: And you should call the image function like this $this->image()

Comment: Do you have a return in the function where $blogId is defined? If so, you can create an array using the variable that is returned and assign the $blogId to a different key and call the function with key to retrieve. Something like `$output[1] .= $this->blogId;`, `return $output;` then call it using `function __construct()[1]`